# Why wait() returns -1 error code?

Tags: c, macos, fork, wait, status

I have the following code:

```
void fork1()
{
    pid_t id, cpid;
    int status;

    id = fork();

    if (id > 0)
    {
        // parent code
        cpid = wait(&status);
        printf("I received from my child %d this information %d\n", cpid, status);
    }
    else if (id == 0)
    {
        // child code
        sleep(2);
        exit(46);
    }
    else
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The output is:

> I received from my child -1 this information 0

So, why I receive the `-1` error code after `wait`? I was expecting to receive the value `46` as status.

**EDIT:**

I added the following piece of code if wait returns -1:

```
printf("errno(%d): %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
```

This is the output:

```
errno(4): Interrupted system call
```

Comment: -1 means that there was an error. Display the errno value to see what the specific error was.

Comment: ... try `perror` function to see what does it says.

Comment: Have you established any signal handlers anywhere ?

Comment: @WojtekSurowka I added errno and perror output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [man page for `wait()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wait) tells you what the return values mean.

> If wait() or waitpid() returns due to the delivery of a signal to the calling process, -1 shall be returned and errno set to [EINTR]....Otherwise, (pid_t)-1 shall be returned, and errno set to indicate the error.

To find out what the `errno` is, you can use [`perror()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) and [`strerror()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror)

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
// ...
perror("wait error: ");
// or
printf("errno(%d): %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
```

From the `wait()` man page the errors could be:

The `wait()` function shall fail if:

> **ECHILD** 
>   The calling process has no existing unwaited-for child processes. 
>   
> **EINTR**
>  
>   The function was interrupted by a signal. The value of the location pointed to by stat_loc is undefined.

So once you print the `errno` value you should have a good idea what went wrong. I don't see anything in your code specifically showing what caused it. A few things you might want to do as good practice, compile with `-Wall` and make sure you're addressing all warnings, and also be sure to initialize all variables.

Comment: You've misused `perror()`: it *prints* the error and returns void and shouldn't be in `printf()`'s argument list here.