# wait() returns -1, errno=10 after launching Python process

Tags: python, c, wait

I have a C program that starts a Python process on a thread. The Python process uses Selenium and files a nuisance call complaint with the FTC. `posix_spawn` is used to keep the C program and Python process separate due to memory leaks in Python. I'm having trouble managing the Python process.

The `wait()` for the Python process is returning `-1`, with `errno` set to `10`. According to the [`wait(2)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) it is an error. I believe `10` is `ECHILD`. `strerror` returns *`No child processes`*.

```
$ ./test.exe
Process started, pid 2730
call_datetime: 2019-04-04 18:07:00
caller_name: PERRYVILLE   MD
caller_number: 4106425608
Wait failed -1, 10
```

Running Python directly with the script results in an expected `0` return code.

```
$ python3 ftc.py --caller_name "PERRYVILLE   MD" --caller_number 4106425608 --call_datetime "2019-04-04 18:07:00"
call_datetime: 2019-04-04 18:07:00
caller_name: PERRYVILLE   MD
caller_number: 4106425608
$ echo "$?"
0
```

I've found two similar questions. The first is at [Linux system() returns -1, ERRNO = 10 No child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22405824/608639). There is not enough information in the question and it was closed. The second question is at [system() returns -1, errno=10 when logged into Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55307361/608639). I don't believe this question applies since `SIGCHLD` is not being handled.

Why is `wait` failing with `ECHILD`?

---

Here is the C program. It calls the Python script and then exits.

The wait code is taken from the [`wait(2)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) example.

```c
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <spawn.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define log_error printf
#define log_info printf
extern char **environ;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    char* const cname = "PERRYVILLE   MD";
    char* const cnumber = "4106425608";
    char* const ctime = "2019-04-04 18:07:00";

    char* const arguments[] = {
        "python3",
        "ftc.py",
        "--caller_name", cname,
        "--caller_number", cnumber,
        "--call_datetime", ctime,
        NULL
    };

    pid_t pid;
    int res = posix_spawn(&pid, "/usr/bin/python3", NULL, NULL, arguments, environ);

    if (res != 0) {
        log_error("Process failed %d, %d\n", res, errno);
        goto do_exit;
    } else {
        log_info("Process started, pid %d\n", pid);
    }

    do
    {
        res = waitpid(pid, &res, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
        if (res == -1) {
            log_error("Wait failed %d, %d\n", res, errno);
            goto do_exit;
        }

        if (WIFEXITED(res)) {
            log_info("Process exited, result %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(res));
        //} else if (WIFSIGNALED(res)) {
        //    log_info("Process signaled, result %d\n", WTERMSIG(res));
        } else if (WIFSTOPPED(res)) {
            log_info("Process stopped, result %d\n", WSTOPSIG(res));
        } else if (WIFCONTINUED(res)) {
            log_info("Process continued\n");
        }
    } while (!WIFEXITED(res) /*&& !WIFSIGNALED(res)*/);

do_exit:

    return (int)WEXITSTATUS(res);
}
```

The C code is compiled with `gcc -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -g3 -O1 -std=c99 -pthread test.c -o test.exe`.

Here is the relevant portion of the Python script. It prints the script arguments and then exits.

```py
$ cat ftc.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import sys

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

def get_option(argv, option):

    argc = len(argv)
    for i in range(0, argc-1):
        if (argv[i] == option and i+1 < argc):
            return argv[i+1]

    return None

def main():

    caller_name = get_option(sys.argv, "--caller_name")
    caller_number = get_option(sys.argv, "--caller_number")
    call_datetime = get_option(sys.argv, "--call_datetime")

    if caller_name is None:
        sys.exit("caller_name is not available")
    if caller_number is None:
        sys.exit("caller_number is not available")
    if call_datetime is None:
        sys.exit("call_datetime is not available")

    print(f"call_datetime: {str(call_datetime)}")
    print(f"caller_name: {str(caller_name)}")
    print(f"caller_number: {str(caller_number)}")

    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I think you meant `ECHILD` for the `errno` value, not `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: And better not to trust these `errno` mapping numbers as they can be different for different platforms. You better to either compare them to your local definitions or use something like `perror` or `strerror`.

Comment: Using `goto do_exit;` and the label instead of using `break;` seems odd.  Not a factor in your problem, but unnecessary use of `goto`.

Comment: Have you tried getting the status of the `SIGCHLD` handling?  A process can inherit `SIG_IGN` for `SIGCHLD`, which might then explain your result.  It would mean your shell is ignoring `SIGCHLD`, I think.  Improbable, but … worth checking because of the dicta of Sherlock Holmes: "Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth."  Testing this will either eliminate the impossible, or show the improbable is true.

Comment: @Jonathan - The `goto` is a vestige of the real code. The real code performs parameter validation in the thread. On failure the `goto` jumps over that particular chunk. The code at the label then delete the `malloc'd` struct used to pass arguments before falling off the thread code.

Comment: Cast close vote for a typo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the wait status with the return value from `waitpid()` here:

```
    res = waitpid(pid, &res, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
```

Use different variables for the return value and the wait status:

```
    int ret = waitpid(pid, &res, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
    if (ret == -1) {
        log_error("Wait failed %d, %d\n", ret, errno);
        goto do_exit;
    }
```